# Log in Windows 8 account automatically, keeping it locked

Tags: windows-8, boot, login

I want my PC to automatically log into my Windows 8 account and run all the startup programs, with out me giving my user name and password. (I have done this myself).

But I also want my PC to be locked until I log in myself. I don't want it to be in an insecure state.

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this if your require to provide a password when you unlock the computer?  Sadly the advice given by Andre is unlikely to work since the default behavior of Windows 8 is to go to the start screen and not straight to the desktop.

Comment: @Ramhound A very common use for this (I see this a lot in the business world) is a program that want's to act like a service and run all the time but it runs in the user's session on startup instead of as a service.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - The terms used doesn't really seem to apply in a case like this.  You do make a good point although a libral policy on locking the computer can also be used to acomplish this without using any third-party software ( even if Autologon is first-party ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [Autologon from Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963905.aspx) but add a scheduled task with a trigger (start at login) and enter this command in the task scheduler

Program: **rundll32.exe** and as parameters: **user32.dll,LockWorkStation**

and create the task. The rundll32 command locks the PC after the automatic logon.

Answer (score 0):

I would master the AutoAdminLogon registry setting. [See detailed article on my website](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/win8/windows8-autoadminlogon-registry.htm)

Then I would create an old-fashioned .bat file, in that file I would put magcandre's suggestion of:
rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation
Then I would put the batch file in the start-up folder:
C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Task Breakdown
1) Logon Automatically 
2) Create a task or script which locks the computer 
3) Run the task in 2) as soon as the user logs on.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is go to the modern UI screen and type "netplwiz" select your account and uncheck user must enter username and password to use this computer. That's it!